# Google not accepting multiple URL parameters in sitemap url?

Tags: php, sitemap, google-search-console

I used to have multiple php pages e.g

```
news.php?id=10, reviews.php?id=10
```

google webmaster tools accepted this sitemap and would index it but i recoded the whole site to reduce the insane amount of php pages i had. now the url looks like this

```
viewpage.php?page-type=news&id=10.
```

This seems fine to me since I'm just using a switch but google doesn't seem to like it and wants me to delete the second variable before it will accept the sitemap but the page won't load if it doesn't have the 2 variables. How do i get around this so that i don't have to revert to the old way of having multiple pages?

i have read the terms on the website and it's giving out saying that I'm creating multiple urls to the same page but i clearly am not.

Comment: Is this `sitemap.xml`? If so, `&` should be encoded to `&amp;`

Comment: thank you kind sir you have saved me a lot of frustration!

Answer (score 0):

As with all XML files, any data values (including URLs) must use entity escape codes for the characters listed in the table below.

```
    Character            Escape Code
---------------------------------------------
    Ampersand       &     &amp;
    Single Quote    '     &apos;
    Double Quote    "     &quot;
    Greater Than    >     &gt;
    Less Than       <     &lt;
```